# Homotopy of paths is trivial?

Tags: algebraic-topology, continuity, homotopy-theory, path-connected

I was thinking of which paths get identified by homotopy (not necessarily relative to their end points). Some innocent drawings seem to suggest that pretty much everything gets identified. My questions are:

1. Given two paths in the same path component are they homotopic?
2. Can an open path be homotopic to a closed path?

---

1. With respect to the first question, given paths $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$, for every $t\in[0,1]$ we have a path $\sigma_t$ from $\gamma_1(t)$ to $\gamma_2(t)$. If one was able to parametrize the $\sigma_t$'s appropriately one would expect $F(s,t)=\sigma_t(s)$ to be a homotopy between the paths. Can one find such a parametrization?
2. With respect to the second question, the method above seems to suggest the answer is yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: any path $\gamma$, open or closed, is homotopic to the constant path $t \mapsto \gamma(1/2)$. Any constant path is homotopic to any other constant path in the same path component.

Comment: Very elegant. Thanks!